# How to verify a user's password in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm having a problem matching user password using devise gem in rails. User password stored on my db which is encrypted_password and i am trying to find user by password, but I don't understand how to match password from form and encrypted_password in my db.

```
User.find_by_email_and_password(params[:user][:email], params[:user][:password])
```

Comment: I think the correct answer has been offered up. Can you select it?

Answer (score 280):

I think this is a better, and more elegant way of doing it:

```
user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])
user.valid_password?(params[:user][:password])
```

The other method where you generate the digest from the user instance was giving me protected method errors.

Comment: password digest is protected, you can get around it this way. User.new.send(:password_digest, 'password')

Comment: but this would lead to guessing the user password in some context, how to check password and still benefit from devise throttling protection?

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, this is exactly what i am searching.

Answer (score 34):

### Use Devise Methods

Devise provides you with **[built-in methods to verify a user's password](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Find-a-user-when-you-have-their-credentials)**:

```
user = User.find_for_authentication(email: params[:user][:email])

user.valid_password?(params[:user][:password])
```

---

For **Rails 4+ with Strong Params**, you can do something like this:

```
def login
  user = User.find_for_authentication(email: login_params[:email])

  if user.valid_password?(login_params[:password])
    user.remember_me = login_params[:remember_me]
    sign_in_and_redirect(user, event: :authentication)
  end
end

private
def login_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :remember_me)
end
```

Comment: Works for my project. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I think the better one will be this

```
valid_password = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email]).valid_password?(params[:user][:password])
```

Comment: That would set user to a boolean value (whether the password was valid or not).

Answer (score 1):

**For 2022**, devise is required to add `:database_authenticatable` to use `valid_password?` method

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :xxxable, :yyyable, :database_authenticatable
```

But, if you need only to verify the entering password just go like [this](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/451ff6d49c71e543962d2b29d77f2e744b2d47e1/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb#L71)

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :xxxable, :yyyable#, :database_authenticatable
  def valid_password?(verifying_word)
    password_digest_instance = BCrypt::Password.new(self.password_digest)
    current_password_salt = password_digest_instance.salt
    hashed_verifying_word_with_same_salt = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(verifying_word, current_password_salt)
    Devise.secure_compare(hashed_verifying_word_with_same_salt, self.password_digest)
```

Then

```
user = User.find_by(email: params[:user][:email])
user = nil unless user.try(:valid_password?, params[:user][:password])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this.

```
user = User.where("email=? OR username=?", email_or_username, email_or_username).first.valid_password?(user_password)
```