# Devise password check

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I use Devise gem for authentication.
How can I check if the password submitted in `params` array is valid?

I try to compare the value of `user.encrypted_password` with `BCrypt::Password.create('password')` but the hash values are different.

May be I need something like salt value?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Just use devise's valid_password? method, for example:

```
user.valid_password?('password123')
```

Answer (score 1):

### From [Devise Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Find-a-user-when-you-have-their-credentials):

You can use the [official solution](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Find-a-user-when-you-have-their-credentials) present on the devise wiki:

```
user = User.find_for_authentication(email: params[:email])
user.valid_password?(params[:password])
```

---

[*Detailed answer for Rails 4+ with Strong Params*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42046418/1533054)