# How to check that old password is equal to that one in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to make a change password in rails i want to enter the old password as a string and check it with the encrypted one in the database i am using Devise gem how can i do this

Comment: Devise provides you with this functionality already. Have a look at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password

Comment: your link was very useful thanks it helped a lot could you please make it as an answer so i could accept it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how verify user password in devise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320921/how-verify-user-password-in-devise)

Comment: @mohamed ok. glad it worked out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devise already provides you with this functionality. It should probably work out of the box using the `edit_user_registration_path`.

Have a look at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password to find some more information.

Answer (score 5):

You want Devise's `valid_password?` method.

```
> user = User.find(1)
> user.valid_password?('invalidpassword')
=> false
> user.valid_password?('therealpassword')
=> true
```